Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheet dismisses automatically when editing text fields in Preview's Interactive Mode but works fine on device
I'm experiencing an issue with Jetpack Compose's ModalBottomSheet in Android Studio's Interactive Preview mode. While the bottom sheet works perfectly when running on a device or emulator, it behaves differently in the Interactive Preview.
Problem:
When the ModalBottomSheet is displayed and I try to edit any TextField inside it, the bottom sheet automatically dismisses itself. This only happens in Interactive Preview mode.
Here's my current implementation:
data class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)

@Composable
fun UserEditor(
    user: User,
    onUserChanged: ((User) -> Unit)?
){
    var firstName by remember { mutableStateOf(user.firstName) }
    var lastName by remember { mutableStateOf(user.lastName) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = firstName,
            onValueChange = { firstName = it },
            label = { Text("First Name") }
        )

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = lastName,
            onValueChange = { lastName = it },
            label = { Text("Last Name") }
        )

        TextButton(
            onClick = {
                onUserChanged?.invoke(User(firstName, lastName))
            }
        ) { Text("Update")}
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun UserEditorModalBottomSheetPreview(){
    var showUserEditor by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var user by remember { mutableStateOf(User("Abc", "Def")) }

    AppTheme {

        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Text("firstName = ${user.firstName} \nlast Name = ${user.lastName}", Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
            TextButton(
                onClick = { showUserEditor = true }
            ) { Text("Edit") }

        }

        if(showUserEditor){
            ModalBottomSheet(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                onDismissRequest = { showUserEditor = false }
            ){
                UserEditor(
                    user = user,
                    onUserChanged = {
                        user = it
                        showUserEditor = false
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

}


The code works fine on real devices and emulators.The issue only occurs in Android Studio's Interactive Preview mode. The bottom sheet dismisses as soon as the TextField gains focus
Environment:

Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2
Compose BOM 2024.10.01

Is this an expected behaviour in interactive mode ?
